# Find all function $f:\mathbb Q^+ \rightarrow \mathbb Q^+$ that satisfy $f(x)+f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)=1$ and $f(2x+1)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> > Find all function $f:\mathbb Q^+ \rightarrow \mathbb Q^+$ that satisfy $$f(x)+f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)=1$$ and $$f(2x+1)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}$$ for all $x$ in domain of $f$

**My Approach:**

Put $x=1$ in $f(x)+f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)=1$

$\implies$

$f(1)+f(1)=1$

$\implies$
$f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Now put $x=2$ in $f(x)+f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)$

we obtain $f(2)+f(\dfrac{1}{2})=1 \cdots \cdots (1)$

Now using $f(2x+1)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}\cdots \cdots (2)$

Put$x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ in eqation $(2)$

$\implies$
$f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)=2f(2)$

Using above result in Equation $(1)$ we obtain $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{3}$

In similar fashion we finally obtain $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ **For Integers**

**I want to know Some other method to solve this**

**I also tried using $g(x)=f(x-1)$ like this [Help in solving a simple functional equation: $3f(2x+1)=f(x) + 5x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3040378/help-in-solving-a-simple-functional-equation-3f2x1-fx-5x). But couldn't get desired result**

**Also this question is similar to [Showing that $f(x)=\frac x{x+1}$ is the unique function satisfying $f(x)+f\left(\frac1x\right)=1$ and $f(2x)=2f\big(f(x)\big)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227678/showing-that-fx-frac-xx1-is-the-unique-function-satisfying-fxf-left)**

Comment: When you say "In similar fashion we finally obtain $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$.. what is the similar fashion?

Comment: @user574848 By using Induction

Comment: But induction works in $\mathbb{N}$ and you are working in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What induction? How do you step from $n$ to $n+1$? In particular, from 3 to 4?